# Changes between two commits in git

Tags: git, git-diff

I have hashes of two commits in a Git repository and I want to get the list of differences between those two commits.

The git log command returns all commits between them but not the differences:

```
git log commit1 commit2
```

Comment: You want to use `git diff commit1 commit2`

Answer (score 2):

As @UnbearableLightness mentioned, you can use the Git diff command like this:

```
git diff commit1 commit2
```

For more information, refer to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).